# Access is denied while docker save

Tags: docker, microservices

I am trying to save a docker image in windows so that I can load to another Linux box,in between while saving the images in windows, I got an error stating access is denied to rename the docker temp file.

I checked the permission everything looks fine, in fact I can able to edit. Any help here is highly appreciable. I am using docker 1.11.0

```
docker save -o . <imgID>
rename .docker_temp_742575903 .: Access is denied.
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Never mind, along with path I need to give my new file name that docker wanted to create and it don't happen implicitly, in my cases I gave

```
docker save -o ./<tar name that you wanted docker to create> <imgID>
```

Comment: me too had same problem...solution is to give file name as well Eg `C:\build\images\image_file_Name` name would be anything you wish

Comment: I provided the path and file name but I still get the error "open c:\.docker_temp_916058883: Access is denied."

Comment: Check if write permission is there for the corresponding user. Usually C drive is for system files trying providing different path.

Comment: I have the same problem as @DarioN1

Comment: edit: @DarioN1  I was able to resolve this issue (using docker toolbox). In the virtual box interface for the docker vm there's an option shared folders where I added a path. Then I went to that folder using the docker console and saved via `docker save <image id> > file.tar`

Comment: This worked for me, first time docker user. thanks! Wish the error messages were more user friendly.

Answer (score 14):

For the similar issue but on unix:

```
root@linux:/opt/docker# docker save -o ./presto.tar starburstdata/presto
open .docker_temp_359214587: permission denied
```

You can use different syntax to save the image as a workaround:

```
root@linux:/opt/docker# docker save starburstdata/presto > presto.tar
root@linux:/opt/docker# ls -l
razem 1356196
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1388737024 maj 23 11:16 presto.tar
```

Comment: Thanks. This does help get past the Linux 'permission denied' error.  My one concern is that the `-o` flag is omitted.  Does it still create a viable restoration file?

Answer (score 8):

I *workaround* the problem on linux by changing the current forlder permission to 777. Make sure your current direct :

```
mkdir ~/docker-images
cd ~/docker-images
chmod 777 ./
sudo docker save <img_id> -o ./<filename>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not giving image name and it's creating some temp name by default but, while renaming that it's throwing error. you can use this command to solve this problem.

```
docker save -o <some custom name with path> <imgID or REPOSITORY:TAG>
```

something like this if you want to create in present directory

```
docker save -o ./ubuntu_image.tar ubuntu:latest
or
docker save -o ./ubuntu_image.tar eat546t
```

If you want to create in specific location

```
docker save -o path/of/image/ubuntu_image.tar ubuntu:latest
```